# parent activity with implicit intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I am successfully using the attribute android:parentActivityName in manifest, in order to set the parent activity (activity A) when another activity (activity B) is started by a push notification, for example. Then, if I go back, I navigate to activity A.

However, it doesn't work with implicit intents. I have an intent-filter declared in manifest for activity B. When activity B is launched from outside the app, it does not seem to effect the attribute android:parentActivityName (or meta-data android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY with lower APIs).

How I can set the parent activity in that case?

The block of manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.domain.app.activities.ActivityB"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
        android:parentActivityName="com.domain.app.activities.ActivityA" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.domain.app.activities.ActivityA" />
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="domain.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From developers documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral

Navigate up with a new back stack
If your activity provides any [intent filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs) that allow other apps to start the activity, you should implement the [onOptionsItemSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) callback such that if the user presses the Up button after entering your activity from another app's task, your app starts a new task with the appropriate back stack before navigating up.

You can do so by first calling [shouldUpRecreateTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#shouldUpRecreateTask(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent)) to check whether the current activity instance exists in a different app's task. If it returns true, then build a new task with [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html). Otherwise, you can use the [navigateUpFromSameTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask(android.app.Activity)) method as shown above.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Note**: In order for the *addNextIntentWithParentStack()* method to work, you must declare the logical parent of each activity in your manifest file, using the *android:parentActivityName* attribute (and corresponding  element) as described above.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in Developer site "specifying your parent activity functionality" is provided in API level 16.

*Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName attribute in the  element.*

and its also state there that for lower api's android provides support library.

*if your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the android:parentActivityName attribute.*

here is the link : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent

and you can also see this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610722/how-to-navigate-to-a-parent-activity)