# Return to parent activity from implicity intent

Tags: android

I am facing the same issue as mentioned in this post - [Parent activity from implicit intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191568/parent-activity-with-implicit-intents)
Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

May not be the right way to do it. But one workaround is 
1. you can have an intermediate activity opened using implicit intent and then 
2. explicitly call your child activity
3. Finish the intermediate activity

Comment: I am a newbie to android, but I think there should definitely be a better solution. This doesn't appear to be an sdk bug or anything